how to transition smoothly between many image textures?
I'm trying to make Minecraft lava, and I have the 20 image textures that make up the animated texture, but In the game it transition smoothly between the images. how would I  achieve this transitioning effect? I have two Ideas, both of which i don't know how to execute.
Idea one: somehow transition smoothly between the image textures In blender.
Idea two: make transition frames as images, and use a regular image sequence node to animate the texture.

due to my lack of knowledge about making gifs, this is all I could get, but hopefully you can see that there are more than 20 image that make up the animated texture.

I separated this image into 20 square images, but it instead of just using the 20 image I need to transition between them using a fade transition

ok, so I'm not sure how to give a visual aid, but the type of transition should be a "fade" and if i was to make transition images, i would want there to be 5 new images in between each of the original images.

Are you sure they transition by fade in Minecraft?

could you point to a video that shows the effect you are talking about?

I achieved my goal by importing a video of the lava in Minecraft into blender, making sure it would render and export as PNG images, made the resolution of each image 16 x 16, and rendered the animation.
